# Working with an array of variants

Tags: excel, vba

I have declared a variant variable in my VBA code, which takes on values from a range. E.g.

```
Dim Output as variant
Output = Range("A1:Z1").value
```

I have declared another array of variants.

```
Dim OutputArray(10000) as variant
```

Each item in this array is an iteration of Output; i.e. OutputArray(0) is the value of Output in the first iteration, OutputArray(1) is the value of Output in the second iteration and so on.

I have two questions:

1. How can I extract individual items from OutputArray; e.g. I want to know the value of cell C1 in 27th iteration?
2. How can I paste the entire array OutputArray on a worksheet in one go? If it is not possible to do so in one go, what's the best option I have?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a new array (1 to 10001, 1 to 26) - populate that from your array of arrays., then put the new array on the sheet.  I think that would be faster than putting each separate sub-array to the sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return C1 on the 27th iteration, it will be something like

```
OutputArray(26)(1,3)
```

I think you will have to paste each iteration separately

- Set the first cell of the range (upper left corner)
- Resize the range to include the size of your iteration.

  - If they are all the same size, you can use a constant; if not, you will have to compute it.
- `R = outputArray(iteration_num)`
- Increment FirstCell depending on where you want the next iteration
- Repeat